# Is there a DBI proxy that handles SQL restrictions and transactions?

Tags: perl, security, proxy, dbi, dbd-proxy

I am looking for a DBI (or similar) proxy that supports both SQL restrictions and transactions. The two I know about are:

- `DBD::Proxy`
- `DBD::Gofer`

## DBD::Proxy

The problem I have found with `DBD::Proxy` is that its server, `DBI::ProxyServer`, doesn't just restrict queries coming in over the network (which I want), but it also restricts queries generated *internally* by the database driver. So, for example, with `DBD::Oracle`, ping no longer works, as well as many other queries it issues itself.

I can't just allow them, because:

- That is quite a bit of internal knowledge of DBD::Oracle and would be quite fragile.
- The whitelist is `query_name => 'sql'`, where `query_name` is the first word of whatever is passed to `prepare`. DBD::Oracle has a lot of internal queries, and the first word of many of them is `select` (duh).

So, it doesn't seem I can use `DBD::Proxy`

## DBD::Gofer

I haven't tried DBD::Gofer, because the docs seem to tell me that I can't use transactions through it:

> ### CONSTRAINTS
>
> ...
>
> **You can’t use transactions**
>
> AutoCommit only. Transactions aren’t supported.

So, before I write my own application-specific proxy (using `RPC::PLServer` ?), is there code out there that solves this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question would be best asked on the DBI Users mailing list, `dbi-users@perl.org`.
Sign up at http://dbi.perl.org/

I'm not sure what you mean about DBD::Proxy restricting queries.  On the only occasion I've used it, it didn't modify the queries at all.

Comment: Look for 'restrict' in the DBI::ProxyServer POD. That'll explain SQL restrictions. I think the answer is "there isn't one". I wrote my app-specific one. But I'll pick this as the answer anyway.